# JS changing a css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm putting something together for work, I've got it working exactly how I want it to, except for one tiny thing. At the bottom of the page, I have 3 circles that work as links to change the slides on my slider, however when I click one it doesn't quite change the css property to change the color of the circle I click on. This might not make sense so I'm going to link my fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/AMN6N/1/) I think it has something specifically to do with this line of code:

```
handleNavClick: function(event, el)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var position = $(el).attr("href").split("-").pop();
    this.el.slider.animate(
    {
        scrollLeft: position * this.slideWidth
    },
    this.timing);
    this.changeActiveNav(el);
},
changeActiveNav: function(el)
{
    this.el.allNavButtons.removeClass("active");
    $(el).addClass("active");
}
};
slider.init();
```

[Here](https://getmeanapprentice.com/apprenticevmsco/SimplyHomepage.html#slide-0) is the temporary link for the webpage.

Comment: your fiddle is messed up, you have JS in the CSS section :-/

Comment: You have the code in the wrong boxes on your fiddle. I have corrected it for you - http://jsfiddle.net/AMN6N/3/

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on `scrollLeft: position * this.slideWidth` here - Is that also the case in your code?

Comment: @haxtbh has fixed the messed up fiddle, and it works as expected.

Comment: [Circle color change working perfectly but not the slider](http://jsfiddle.net/AMN6N/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Illidanek Pay attention. That line is part of an object literal. A `;` would break it.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help guys ill get back and see if i can replicate the results just noticed the error on my js @Illidanek

Comment: You also appear to be calling your JS file twice in your `<head>`. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getmeanapprentice.com/apprenticevmsco/SimplySliderTest.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="SimplySliderTest.js"></script>`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions why it isnt work on the temporary webpage

Comment: haxtbh i have now removed one of them, however it still doesnt want to work on the web page, am i missing a link to a javascript resource

Comment: @user3592455 you need to remove the `; `from `scrollLeft: position * this.slideWidth;`. This is breaking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to load just one SimplySliderTest.js file.

The elements are loading after the javascript is being executed so nothing is binding to them.

You have two options:

1. Load the JS inside SimplySliderTest.js when the page has loaded. i.e.

   ```
   $(function(){

   var slider = 
       {
       el:
       {
           slider: $("#slider"),
           allSlides: $(".slide"),
           sliderNav: $(".slider-nav"),
           allNavButtons: $(".slider-nav > a")
       },

       timing: 800,
       slideWidth: 300,

       init: function() 
       {
           this.bindUIEvents();
       },

       bindUIEvents: function() 
       {
           this.el.slider.on("scroll", function(event)
           {
               slider.moveSlidePosition(event);
           });
           this.el.sliderNav.on("click", "a", function(event)
           {
               slider.handleNavClick(event, this);
           });
       },
       moveSlidePosition: function(event)
       {
           this.el.allSlides.css(
           {
               "background-position": $(event.target).scrollLeft()/6-100+ "px 0"
           });
       },
       handleNavClick: function(event, el)
       {
           event.preventDefault();
           var position = $(el).attr("href").split("-").pop();
           this.el.slider.animate(
           {
               scrollLeft: position * this.slideWidth
           },
           this.timing);
           this.changeActiveNav(el);
       },
       changeActiveNav: function(el)
       {
           this.el.allNavButtons.removeClass("active");
           $(el).addClass("active");
       }
       };
       slider.init();
   });
   ```
2. Move you `<script type="text/javascript" src="SimplySliderTest.js"></script>` to the bottom of your page so it loads after the elements

Comment: that code was great worked a charm, however, i seem to have broke it more as now the 2nd and 3rd image wont show [link](https://getmeanapprentice.com/apprenticevmsco/SimplyHomepage.html#slide-0) i don't actually know what i've done here

Comment: @user3592455 revert `"background-position": $(event.target).scrollLeft()` to `"background-position": $(event.target).scrollLeft()/6-100+ "px 0"` inside the `moveSlidePosition:` function. Also mark the answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem :)